# Select all elements that don't start with a certain id

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a way to get all the elements that don't start with the id `foo` in JavaScript?

I tried the following:

`var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id!=foo]');`

That doesn't work.

Basically I want the opposite of:

`var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=foo]');`

Comment: Since that's going to return every element except one (because id values should be unique), it might be easier to just get them all and skip the one with the target id during processing.

Comment: First, your markup is invalid if you have repeated IDs.

Comment: edited the question, my bad sry.

Comment: `Id` attribute must be unique on the page. So, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`:not()` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not):

```
document.querySelectorAll(":not([id^='foo'])");
```

Comment: Close, but it should be: `document.querySelectorAll(":not([id^='foo'])")` (starts with).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`:not` pseudo selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to match everything except `[id^="foo"]`:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(':not([id^=foo])');
```

Comment: Close, but it should be: `document.querySelectorAll(":not([id^='foo'])")` (starts with).

Comment: I think the question was updated after we read it.  I made the same mistake, and don't remember seeing it there before.  (It was edited)

Comment: *get all the elements that don't start with the id foo* - This does that.

Comment: @ScottMarcus the OP has modified!

Answer (score 0):

Just select all and then filter out the one with the id

```
document.querySelectorAll("*").filter(...)
```